# How to unit test newly created object inside method?

Tags: android, junit, junit4, android-testing, android-junit

I have PaymentPresenter with method payWorkOrder(). That method accepts some parameters and based on the logic created two new objects:

1. WoPayment
2. PaymentRequest

Here is the code for that:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) @PrepareForTest({TextUtils.class})
public class PaymentPresenterTest extends BaseTest {

@Rule TrampolineSchedulerRule trampolineSchedulerRule = new  TrampolineSchedulerRule();

@Mock CustomersRepository customersRepository;
@Mock AgreementsRepository agreementsRepository;
@Mock WorkOrdersRepository workOrdersRepository;
@Mock PaymentPresenter.View view;
@Mock ResponseBody responseBody;

private PaymentPresenter presenter;

@Before public void setUp() {
mockTextUtils();
presenter = new PaymentPresenter(customersRepository,  agreementsRepository, workOrdersRepository);
presenter.setView(view);
}

public void payWorkOrderInvoice(int workOrderId, double amount, String paymentMethod, String checkNumber) {
disposables = RxUtil.initDisposables(disposables);

WoPayment woPayment = new WoPayment();

if(amount > 0) {
  woPayment.setAmount(amount);
} else {
  view.displayAmountShouldBeGreaterThanZero();
  return;
}

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(paymentMethod)) {
  view.displayPaymentMethodInvalid();
  return;
} else {
  woPayment.setPaymentMethod(paymentMethod);
}

if(paymentMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("Check") && TextUtils.isEmpty(checkNumber)) {
  view.displayReferenceNumberError();
  return;
} else {
  woPayment.setCheckNumber(checkNumber);
}

view.disablePayButton();

Disposable disposable = workOrdersRepository.payWorkOrderInvoice(workOrderId, new PaymentRequest(woPayment))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(response -> {
      if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        view.displayWorkOrderInvoicePaid(response.body());
      } else {
        view.enablePayButton();
        view.displayWorkOrderInvoiceNotPaid();
      }
      }, throwable -> {
      view.enablePayButton();
      view.handleError(throwable);
    });

disposables.add(disposable);
}
}
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
@Test public void shouldPayWorkOrderInvoice() {
// Given
int workOrderId = 1;
double amount = 1.0;
String paymentMethod = "cash";
String checkNumber = "1";
WorkOrderDetails workOrderDetails = Mockito.mock(WorkOrderDetails.class);
Response<WorkOrderDetails> response = Response.success(200, workOrderDetails);
WoPayment woPayment = new WoPayment();
woPayment.setAmount(amount);
woPayment.setCheckNumber(checkNumber);
woPayment.setPaymentMethod(paymentMethod);
PaymentRequest paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(woPayment);

// When
Mockito.when(workOrdersRepository.payWorkOrderInvoice(workOrderId, paymentRequest)).thenReturn(Single.just(response));
presenter.payWorkOrderInvoice(workOrderId, amount, paymentMethod, checkNumber);

// Then
Mockito.verify(view).displayWorkOrderInvoicePaid(workOrderDetails);
}
```

But it fails with the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.test.presentation.agreements.payment.PaymentPresenter.payWorkOrderInvoice(PaymentPresenter.java:168)
>     at
>   com.test.presentation.agreements.PaymentPresenterTest.shouldPayWorkOrderInvoice(PaymentPresenterTest.java:175)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)  at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$LastRuleTestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:148)
>     at
>   com.test.presentation.core.TrampolineSchedulerRule$1.evaluate(TrampolineSchedulerRule.java:21)

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace says that in the file PaymentPresenter.java in line 168, there is an access to an object that is 'null', i.e. not instantiated. So take a look at that line and try to find out why the object is not instantiated. It is hard to tell without having the line numbers of your files.

Comment: Disposable disposable = workOrdersRepository.payWorkOrderInvoice(workOrderId, new PaymentRequest(woPayment))

Comment: That is this line. It seems that is related to new PaymenetRequest(woPayment)

Comment: It seems like the 'workOrdersRepository' variable has not been initialized. Can you show how you initialize it?

Comment: That is initialized for sure since I do not have issues with that on other unit tests in the same class. I have initialised it with @Mock annotation. I think that issues is with local scope of new objects created inside the method. I am talking about WoPayment and PaymentRequest. They are created locally inside that method, but I do not mock them. I am not sure how to mock them.

Comment: Ok, I do not think I can provide any further support because I lack information here. Can you provide a piece of code that is runnable and reproduces the problem? With the code seen so far I cannot reproduce the problem because I do not see how for example the 'workOrdersRepository' is initialized. That means I cannot run this code.

Comment: I tried to use only the essence of your code and with the resulting code, the workOrdersRepository was also not instantiated (I got a NullPointerException). I think Mockito is not initialized correctly. I tried to use `workOrdersRepository = Mockito.mock(WorkOrdersRepository.class);` instead of the `@Mock` annotation and that worked for me.